# How to send push notification with "npm request" to ionic API?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, request, ionic2

I tried to push notification by ionic API with "npm request". My code:

```
var request = require('request');
var token = '................';

var title = escapeJson('title 123');
var message = escapeJson('message 123');

var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
  },
  data: {
    "tokens": ["........"],
    "profile": "pushserver",
    "notification": {
      "title": title,
      "message": message,
      "android": {
        "title": title,
        "message": message
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I got this Error:

> {"meta": {"version": "2.0.0-beta.0", "status": 422, "request_id":
>   "853be189-87e0-4636-b58a-aca58cef63b3"}, "error": {"message": "Invalid
>   JSON in request body. For empty JSON, pass '{}'.", "type":
>   "UnprocessableEntity", "link": null}}

Someone know what is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed "data" to "body" and now it is working:

```
var req = {
  "method": "POST",
  "url": "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
  },
  "body": {
    "tokens": ["........"],
    "profile": "pushserver",
    "notification": {
      "title": title,
      "message": message,
      "android": {
        "title": title,
        "message": message
      }
    }
  }
};
```